# Is any form to duplicate the account table in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, tab

[image]

Hello, the button "Validar cuenta" take me to a visualforce page, I'm traying to figure it out how that page can look exactly as the account table, with the same bar, and same button (new)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the Visualforce page you're seeing is using the [standard `<apex:enhancedList>` component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) or the [standard `<apex:listViews>` component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_listViews.htm).

In either case, you should be able to see what is actually being used by looking at the Visualforce page itself (assuming you have the appropriate permissions). You should be able to get the name of the Visualforce page by looking at the URL after you click the button, or by looking at the button's metadata (through the setup menu).